# How to change the interact language back to English from Simplified Chinese in DrRacket

Tags: racket

Just getting start using DrRacket, but it automatically set the environment in Simplified Chinese after I finished installing it.

I've seen the tutorial that is included with drracket:

```
C:\Program Files\Racket\doc\drracket\Menus.html#part._.Help
```

However my help button in Simplified Chinese does not contain the option "Interact with DrRacket in English"

Is there another way to change the language of the environment back to English?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ensure you have this line in your `~/.racket/racket-prefs.rktd`:

```
(plt:human-language english)
```

(Tested against version 5.2.1.)

Comment: it works! thx~ btw, in order to find the file "racket-prefs.rktd" in Windows, I need to find the hidden "Application Data" folder first. more on (http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/drracket-files.html)

Comment: Confirmed to still work on 6.4 (2016). To find the Racket config folder on Windows just press windows+R (for run) then `%appdata%`.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: Sorry. I didn't read the question careful enough before posting my answer, since the question already states that the Help menu option was not available. However, I tested to change the interaction language to both Chinese variants and back to English with the current version and it works. Maybe the screenshot helps somebody else to find this setting more quickly.*

You can also directly use the GUI menu `Help` to change the interaction language (tested with the current version of DrRacket 7.3), e.g. by selecting `Interact with DrRacket in English`.

[image: Help menu of DrRacket with options to select interaction language]